# Why is my Read the Docs build failing?

Tags: python, read-the-docs

I'm trying to make documentation with read the docs for a dummy package, to learn how to use RTD. I followed this [tutorial](http://dont-be-afraid-to-commit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation.html) and successfully made `index.html` and pushed my changes to git (though I'm using gitlab instead of github to host my code). However I cannot get it to be hosted on RTD.

I've connected RTD to my gitlab project via a webhook (and tested it on gitlab; it passed the test). I have both the gitlab project and the RTD project set to public. However I've tried building a version on RTD and it fails every time, without providing a warning/reason.

The first few times when I clicked on the RTD link for my project it said the page doesn't exist, now I get the following error:

`Permission Denied
You don't have the proper permissions to view this page. Please contact the owner of this project to request permission.`

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

try to open cmd as administrator and then:

```
idle pythonPath.py
```

or if you are using linux

```
sudo idle pythonPath.py
```

Comment: What should be in this file? Do I need to add anything to it?